# Database check in a loop

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, mysql

I have a python script that loads a database table and checks an API for the entries found.

I do it like this:

```
import threading
import constants
import pymysql
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
import os
import urllib.request
import shutil
import json


class CheckStreams(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, debug):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.debug = debug
        self.newGames = False
        self.online = 0

  def get_new_games(self):
        return self.newGames

  def set_new_games(self):
        self.newGames = True

  def get_online(self):
        return self.online

  def set_online(self):
        self.online += 1

  def run(self):

    # Connect to the database
    connect = pymysql.connect(host=constants.HOST,
                              user=constants.USERNAME,
                              password=constants.PASSWORD,
                              db=constants.DATABASE,
                              charset='utf8mb4',
                              port=constants.PORT,
                              cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    # Get Streamer Table #
    try:

        with connect.cursor() as cursor:

            # Read all Streamers #
            sql = "SELECT * FROM `ls_streamer` s LEFT JOIN `ls_platforms` p ON s.platform = p.id"

            # Execute Query #
            cursor.execute(sql)

            # Result to streamers Var #
            streamers = cursor.fetchall()

            # Check if we have Streamers at all #
            if cursor.rowcount > 0:

                # Show total Streamers #
                if self.debug: print('Total Streamers: %s' % constants.color('green', cursor.rowcount))

                # Loop through all streamers #
                for streamer in streamers:

                    # Output Current Streamer #
                    if self.debug: print(
                        '\n%s - %s' % (
                        streamer["channel_user"], constants.color(streamer["name"], streamer["name"])))

                    # Fetch from Platform #
                    if streamer["platform"] == 1:

                        # Twitch.tv #
                        if self.debug: print('Gathering %s' % constants.color('Twitch.tv', 'Twitch.tv'))
                        # gatherTwitch()
                        self.gatherTwitch(streamer)
                        #self.gatherTwitchVods(streamer)
                    else:

                        # None #
                        if self.debug: print(
                            'Wrong Platform ID: #%s' % constants.color('red', streamer["platform"]))

            else:
                if self.debug: print('Total Streamers: %s' % constants.color('red', '0'))

    except Exception:
        constants.PrintException()

    finally:
        connect.close()


def gatherTwitch(self, streamer):

    # Connect to the database
    connect = pymysql.connect(host=constants.HOST,
                              user=constants.USERNAME,
                              password=constants.PASSWORD,
                              db=constants.DATABASE,
                              charset='utf8mb4',
                              port=constants.PORT,
                              cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    # Internal Vars #
    isOnline = False
    description = None
    language = None
    thumbnail = None
    setOffline = False
    banner = "None"
    logo = "None"
    partner = False

    # Create Stream Url from Vars #
    streamUrl = '%s%s' % (streamer["url"], streamer["channel_id"])

    # Send Request w/ Twitch Headers #
    r = requests.get(
        streamUrl,
        headers=
        {
            "Accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json",
            "Client-ID": constants.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID
        }
    )

    # Check Response Code #
    if r.status_code == 200:

        # JSON #
        data = r.json()

        # Check if Stream is valid #
        if "stream" in data.keys():

            # Get Info #
            streamData = data["stream"]
            if type(streamData) is dict:

                # Check if Streaming LoL #
                if streamData["game"].lower() == "league of legends":

                    # Streaming LoL - YAY #
                    if self.debug: print('%s' % constants.color('green', 'IS STREAMING'))

                    # Gather Vars #
                    lastSeen = datetime.now()
                    if streamer["is_online"] == True:
                        lastSeen = streamer["modified"]

                    totalStreamed = streamer["total_online"]
                    totalStreamed += constants.convertTimeDelta((datetime.now() - lastSeen))

                    viewers = streamData["viewers"]
                    resolution = streamData["video_height"]
                    fps = streamData["average_fps"]
                    delay = streamData["delay"]
                    started = parse(streamData["created_at"], None, ignoretz=True)
                    isOnline = True

                    # Channel Data #
                    channelData = streamData["channel"]
                    if type(channelData) is dict:

                        description = channelData["status"]
                        language = channelData["language"]
                        logo = channelData["logo"]
                        banner = channelData["profile_banner"]
                        if channelData["partner"] == "true":
                            partner = True
                        if channelData["partner"] is True:
                            partner = True

                    else:
                        # Output Debug #
                        if self.debug: print('Channel Data %s' % constants.color('red', 'NOT FOUND'))

                    # Peview Data #
                    previewData = streamData["preview"]
                    if type(previewData) is dict:

                        thumbnail = previewData["medium"]

                    else:
                        # Output Debug #
                        if self.debug: print('Preview Data %s' % constants.color('red', 'NOT FOUND'))

                    try:
                        with connect.cursor() as cursorStreamer:

                            # Got all Vars put to DB #
                            sqlUpdate = """
                            UPDATE
                              `ls_streamer`
                            SET
                              total_online = %s,
                              viewers = %s,
                              resolution = %s,
                              fps = %s,
                              delay = %s,
                              description = %s,
                              language = %s,
                              thumbnail = %s,
                              logo = %s,
                              banner = %s,
                              started = %s,
                              is_online = %s,
                              modified = %s,
                              is_partner = %s
                            WHERE
                              id = %s
                            """

                            # Execute Query #
                            connect.escape(sqlUpdate)
                            cursorStreamer.execute(sqlUpdate, (
                                totalStreamed, viewers, resolution, fps, delay, description, language, thumbnail,
                                logo, banner, started, isOnline, datetime.now(), partner, streamer["id"]))
                            connect.commit()
                            self.set_online()

                            # Now crawl the Riot API for Live Games for all connected summoners #
                            self.getLiveGames(streamer)

                    except Exception:
                        constants.PrintException()

                    finally:
                        if self.debug: print('Update ls_streamer: %s' % constants.color('green', 'SUCCESS'))

                else:

                    # Set Offline #
                    setOffline = True
                    # Stream online but not streaming LoL #
                    if self.debug: print(
                        'Stream is %s but %s streaming LoL' % (
                        constants.color('green', 'online'), constants.color('red', 'NOT')))

            else:

                # Set Offline #
                setOffline = True
                # Output Debug #
                if self.debug: print('Streamer is %s' % constants.color('red', 'OFFLINE'))

        else:

            # Set Offline #
            setOffline = True
            # Output Debug #
            if self.debug: print('Streamer is %s' % constants.color('red', 'OFFLINE'))

    else:

        # Set Offline #
        setOffline = True

        # Output Debug #
        if self.debug: print('->%s %s' % ('Response Code', constants.color('red', r.status_code)))

        # Output Url #
        if self.debug: print('Streamer Url: %s' % streamUrl)

    if setOffline == True:
        try:
            with connect.cursor() as cursorStreamerOff:

                # Got all Vars put to DB #
                sqlOffline = """
                   UPDATE
                     `ls_streamer`
                   SET
                     is_online = %s
                   WHERE
                     id = %s
                   """

                # Execute Query #
                connect.escape(sqlOffline)
                cursorStreamerOff.execute(sqlOffline, (False, streamer["id"]))
                connect.commit()

        except Exception:
            constants.PrintException()

    # Create Stream Url from Vars #
    streamUrlVod = '%s%s/videos?broadcast_type=archive&limit=100' % (
    streamer["channelurl"], streamer["channel_id"])

    # Send Request w/ Twitch Headers #
    rVod = requests.get(
        streamUrlVod,
        headers=
        {
            "Accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json",
            "Client-ID": constants.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID
        }
    )

    # Check Response Code #
    if rVod.status_code == 200:

        # JSON #
        data = rVod.json()

        # Check if Stream is valid #
        if "videos" in data.keys():
            # Get Info #
            videos = data["videos"]

            for video in videos:

                thumb = video["preview"]["medium"]
                video_id = video["_id"]
                length = video["length"]
                created = video["created_at"]
                if video["game"] == "League of Legends" and video["viewable"] == "public":

                    # Check if video exists #
                    try:
                        with connect.cursor() as cursorVod:
                            sqlInsert = """
                                INSERT INTO
                                  `ls_vods`
                                  (streamer_id, thumbnail, video_id, created, `length`, last_check)
                                VALUES
                                  (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                                  last_check = %s,
                                  thumbnail = %s,
                                  `length` = %s
                            """

                            cursorVod.execute(sqlInsert,
                                           (streamer["id"], thumb, video_id, created, length, datetime.now(), datetime.now(), thumb, length))
                            connect.commit()
                    except Exception:
                        constants.PrintException()
        else:
            if self.debug: print('Videos not found in URL: %s' % streamUrl)
    else:
        # Output Debug #
        if self.debug: print('->%s %s' % ('Response Code', constants.color('red', r.status_code)))

        # Output Url #
        if self.debug: print('Streamer Url: %s' % streamUrl)

def getLiveGames(self, streamer):

    # Connect to the database
    connect = pymysql.connect(host=constants.HOST,
                              user=constants.USERNAME,
                              password=constants.PASSWORD,
                              db=constants.DATABASE,
                              charset='utf8mb4',
                              port=constants.PORT,
                              cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    # Select all Summoners from Streamer #
    try:
        with connect.cursor() as cursorSummoner:
            sqlSummoner = """
            SELECT * FROM
              `ls_summoner` s
            LEFT JOIN
              `ls_regions` r
            ON
              r.id = s.region_id
            WHERE
              streamer_id = %s
            """

            # Execute Query #
            cursorSummoner.execute(sqlSummoner, (streamer["id"],))
            summoners = cursorSummoner.fetchall()

            if cursorSummoner.rowcount > 0:

                for summoner in summoners:

                    # Output which Summoner #
                    if self.debug: print('Checking Live Game for Summoner %s-%s' % (
                        summoner["short"].upper(), summoner["name"]))

                    urlLive = "https://%s.api.riotgames.com/lol/spectator/v3/active-games/by-summoner/%s?api_key=%s" % (
                        summoner["long"].lower(), summoner["summoner_id"],
                        constants.RIOT_API_KEY)

                    r = requests.get(urlLive)

                    if self.debug: print("Checking %s" % urlLive)

                    # Check Response Code #
                    if r.status_code == 200:

                        # Output #
                        if self.debug: print('->%s Found Live Game for %s-%s' % (
                            constants.color('green', 'FOUND'), summoner["short"].upper(), summoner["name"]))

                        # JSON #
                        game = r.json()

                        # Gather Vars #
                        map = game["mapId"]
                        gameId = game["gameId"]
                        gameMode = game["gameMode"]
                        gameType = game["gameType"]
                        queueId = game["gameQueueConfigId"]
                        played = game["gameLength"]
                        spell1Id = None
                        spell2Id = None
                        teamId = None
                        champion = None
                        runes = None
                        masteries = None

                        pp = game["participants"]
                        if type(pp) is list:
                            for part in pp:
                                if part["summonerId"] == summoner["summoner_id"]:
                                    teamId = part["teamId"]
                                    spell1Id = part["spell1Id"]
                                    spell2Id = part["spell2Id"]
                                    champion = part["championId"]
                                    runes = json.dumps(part["runes"])
                                    masteries = json.dumps(part["masteries"])

                        if self.debug: print('Game %s. Game ID #%s' % (constants.color('green', 'found'), gameId))

                        # MySQL #
                        try:
                            with connect.cursor() as cursorUpdateCurrent:

                                # Check Champion in DB #
                                sqlChampion = "SELECT * FROM `ls_champions` WHERE id = %s"
                                cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlChampion,
                                                            (champion,))
                                if cursorUpdateCurrent.rowcount == 0:
                                    # Champion not in DB TODO: SEND MAIL #
                                    if self.debug: print("Champion %",
                                                         constants.color('red',
                                                                         'NOT IN DB'))
                                    # Exit current Game Update #
                                    break

                                # Check Map in DB #
                                sqlMap = "SELECT * FROM `ls_maps` WHERE id = %s"
                                cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlMap,
                                                            (map,))
                                if cursorUpdateCurrent.rowcount == 0:
                                    # Map not in DB TODO: SEND MAIL #
                                    if self.debug: print("Map %",
                                                         constants.color('red',
                                                                         'NOT IN DB'))
                                    # Exit current Game Update #
                                    break

                                # Check Queue in DB #
                                sqlQueue = "SELECT * FROM `ls_queues` WHERE id = %s"
                                cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlQueue,
                                                            (queueId,))
                                if cursorUpdateCurrent.rowcount == 0:
                                    # Queue not in DB TODO: SEND MAIL #
                                    if self.debug: print("Queue %",
                                                         constants.color('red',
                                                                         'NOT IN DB'))
                                    # Exit current Game Update #
                                    break

                                # Check P1Spell1 in DB #
                                sqlP1Spell1 = "SELECT * FROM `ls_spells` WHERE id = %s"
                                cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlP1Spell1,
                                                            (spell1Id,))
                                if cursorUpdateCurrent.rowcount == 0:
                                    # P1Spell1 not in DB TODO: SEND MAIL #
                                    if self.debug: print("P1Spell1 %",
                                                         constants.color('red',
                                                                         'NOT IN DB'))
                                    # Exit current Game Update #
                                    break

                                # Check P1Spell2 in DB #
                                sqlP1Spell2 = "SELECT * FROM `ls_spells` WHERE id = %s"
                                cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(
                                    sqlP1Spell2,
                                    (spell2Id,))
                                if cursorUpdateCurrent.rowcount == 0:
                                    # P1Spell2 not in DB TODO: SEND MAIL #
                                    if self.debug: print("P1Spell2 %",
                                                         constants.color('red',
                                                                         'NOT IN DB'))
                                    # Exit current Game Update #
                                    break

                                # Select Current Match #
                                sqlSelectCurrent = " SELECT * FROM `ls_current_match` WHERE summoner_id = %s"

                                cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlSelectCurrent, (summoner["id"]))

                                if cursorUpdateCurrent.rowcount > 0:

                                    # Found a Current Match #
                                    sqlUpdateCurrent = """
                                    UPDATE
                                      `ls_current_match`
                                    SET
                                      champion_id = %s,
                                      map_id = %s,
                                      summoner_id = %s,
                                      queue_id = %s,
                                      match_id = %s,
                                      team = %s,
                                      length = %s,
                                      type = %s,
                                      mode = %s,
                                      modified = %s,
                                      p1_spell1_id = %s,
                                      p1_spell2_id = %s,
                                      is_playing = %s,
                                      runes = %s,
                                      masteries = %s
                                    WHERE
                                      summoner_id = %s
                                    """

                                    cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(
                                        sqlUpdateCurrent, (
                                            champion,
                                            map,
                                            summoner["id"],
                                            queueId,
                                            gameId,
                                            teamId,
                                            played,
                                            gameType,
                                            gameMode,
                                            datetime.now(),
                                            spell1Id,
                                            spell2Id,
                                            True,
                                            runes,
                                            masteries, summoner["id"]
                                        ))

                                    connect.commit()
                                    if self.debug: print(
                                        '%s Current Match in Database\n' % constants.color('yellow',
                                                                                           'UPDATED'))



                                else:

                                    # No current Match for Summoner Id found #
                                    sqlNewCurrent = """
                                    INSERT INTO
                                      `ls_current_match`
                                    (champion_id, map_id, summoner_id, queue_id, match_id, team, length, type, mode, modified, p1_spell1_id, p1_spell2_id, is_playing, runes, masteries)
                                    VALUES
                                    (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                                    """

                                    cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlNewCurrent, (
                                        champion,
                                        map,
                                        summoner["id"],
                                        queueId,
                                        gameId,
                                        teamId,
                                        played,
                                        gameType,
                                        gameMode,
                                        datetime.now(),
                                        spell1Id,
                                        spell2Id,
                                        True,
                                        runes,
                                        masteries
                                    ))

                                    connect.commit()
                                    if self.debug: print(
                                        '%s Current Match in Database\n' % constants.color(
                                            'green', 'INSERTED'))





                        except Exception:
                            constants.PrintException()

                        # TODO: ENTER TO MATCHES DB #
                        # RESONS: If Game Ends and new One Starts before its detected in the While Loop, it gets overwritten #

                        # Exit if One Playing found #
                        break


                    else:
                        # Response Code not 200 #
                        if self.debug: print(
                            '->%s %s' % ('Response Code', constants.color('red', r.status_code)))

                        # Reset Games in Current Matches #
                        try:
                            with connect.cursor() as cursorUpdateCurrent:
                                # Select Current Match #
                                sqlSelectCurrent = "SELECT * FROM `ls_current_match` WHERE summoner_id = %s"
                                cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlSelectCurrent, (summoner["id"]))

                                if cursorUpdateCurrent.rowcount == 0:

                                    # Output not found in Current Match -> has never played #
                                    if self.debug: print(
                                        'Not found, Summoner %s' % constants.color('yellow', 'NEVER PLAYED'))

                                else:

                                    # Set isPlaying = false #
                                    sqlSelectCurrent = "UPDATE  `ls_current_match`  SET  is_playing = %s WHERE summoner_id = %s"
                                    cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlSelectCurrent, (False, summoner["id"]))
                                    connect.commit()

                                    if self.debug: print(
                                        '%s Current Match in Database, set isPlaying = false\n' % constants.color(
                                            'green', 'UPDATED'))

                                    # Create new Matchc in MatchHistory #
                                    sqlSelectCurrentRe = " SELECT * FROM `ls_current_match` WHERE summoner_id = %s"
                                    cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlSelectCurrentRe, (summoner["id"]))
                                    cG = cursorUpdateCurrent.fetchone()

                                    # See if Match in MatchHistory ->should not be the case #
                                    sqlSelectMatch = "SELECT * FROM  `ls_matches` WHERE match_id = %s AND streamer = %s"
                                    cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(sqlSelectMatch, (cG["match_id"], streamer["id"]))

                                    if cursorUpdateCurrent.rowcount == 0:

                                        sqlNewMatch = """
                                        INSERT INTO
                                          `ls_matches`
                                          (streamer, champion, map, match_id, team, lane, role, length, type, win, modified, crawled, summoner, region)
                                        VALUES
                                          (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                                        """

                                        cursorUpdateCurrent.execute(
                                            sqlNewMatch, (
                                                streamer["id"],
                                                cG["champion_id"],
                                                cG["map_id"],
                                                cG["match_id"],
                                                cG["team"],
                                                'NONE',
                                                'NONE',
                                                cG["length"],
                                                cG["type"],
                                                1,
                                                datetime.now(),
                                                False,
                                                cG["summoner_id"],
                                                summoner["region_id"]

                                            ))

                                        connect.commit()

                                    else:

                                        # Output that Match already exists !?? #
                                        if self.debug: print('Match-ID %s %s' % (
                                            cG["match_id"], constants.color('yellow', 'already crawled')))

                                    self.set_new_games()

                        except Exception:
                            constants.PrintException()
            else:
                # No Summoners for Streamer #
                if self.debug: print("%s found" % constants.color('red', 'NO SUMMONERS'))

    except Exception:
        constants.PrintException()
```

This works okay-ish but as the table grows it takes so much longer for the individual entries to be checked. Currently it takes about 1 second to check the API per entry and I have around 300 entries. So a whole db check takes ~300 seconds. As the database grows the checks take longer and longer. But I don't want the first entry to be updated every 1000+ seconds if I have 1000+ entries.

Is there a way to multi-thread this without spawning a thread for each entry/db-id? Also the table updates frequently (added and deleted rows).

I am coming from a PHP background, so threading isn't anything I have worked with before, and I only have little understanding of it. Currently the `CheckStreams` function is one of three threads my main class spawns.

If any of that does not make sense or needs more details, please let me know!